# Stopwatch label output

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I have a button which you have to click and it measures the reactiontime. In the 2 player mode ( 15 clicks for the player 10 and 15 clicks for player 2). The time I give out in two labels. But why is the text of the labelSummary2 the text of the other label? ( I want to get the reactiontimes in both labels so I'm able to compare them...)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    _Stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
    _ReactionTimes = new List<TimeSpan>();
    _ReactionTimes2 = new List<TimeSpan>();
}

private void txbStart_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{    
    if (Spielzuege2 >= 16)
    {
        _Stopwatch2.Reset();
        _Stopwatch2.Start();
    }
    else 
    {
        _Stopwatch.Reset();
        _Stopwatch.Start();
    }
}

private void btnRot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Spielzuege2 >= 16)
    {               
        _Stopwatch2.Stop();
        _ReactionTimes2.Add(_Stopwatch2.Elapsed);
        labelSummary2.Text = String.Format("Player 2: Current: {0:0.000} s Minimum: {1:0.000} s    Maximum: {2:0.000} s", _ReactionTimes.Last().TotalSeconds, _ReactionTimes.Min().TotalSeconds, _ReactionTimes.Max().TotalSeconds);
    }
    else
    {
        _Stopwatch.Stop();
        _ReactionTimes.Add(_Stopwatch.Elapsed);
        labelSummary.Text = String.Format("Player 1: Current: {0:0.000} s    Minimum: {1:0.000} s    Maximum: {2:0.000} s", _ReactionTimes.Last().TotalSeconds, _ReactionTimes.Min().TotalSeconds, _ReactionTimes.Max().TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace following code for your button click event :

```
private void btnRot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Spielzuege2 >= 16)
    {               
        _Stopwatch2.Stop();
        _ReactionTimes2.Add(_Stopwatch2.Elapsed);
        labelSummary2.Text = String.Format("Player 2: Current: {0:0.000} s Minimum: {1:0.000} s    Maximum: {2:0.000} s", _ReactionTimes2.Last().TotalSeconds, _ReactionTimes2.Min().TotalSeconds, _ReactionTimes2.Max().TotalSeconds);
    }
    else
    {
        _Stopwatch.Stop();
        _ReactionTimes.Add(_Stopwatch.Elapsed);
        labelSummary.Text = String.Format("Player 1: Current: {0:0.000} s    Minimum: {1:0.000} s    Maximum: {2:0.000} s", _ReactionTimes.Last().TotalSeconds, _ReactionTimes.Min().TotalSeconds, _ReactionTimes.Max().TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `_ReactionTimes` List to fill both labels, instead of using `_ReactionTimes2` for `labelSummary2`:

```
labelSummary2.Text = String.Format("Player 2: Current: {0:0.000} s Minimum: {1:0.000} s    Maximum: {2:0.000} s", _ReactionTimes.Last().TotalSeconds, _ReactionTimes.Min().TotalSeconds, _ReactionTimes.Max().TotalSeconds);
```